# Powershell pattern matching

Tags: powershell

I have a requirement to create directories based on a numeric 9 digit with leading zeros primary key from an order entry database on a remote server.
Each morning a new directory should be created. The directory name will be the primary key number of the new customer.  I already have the sql statement extracting the primary key information into a text file using BCP that preserves the leading zeros.
This file is transferred from the database server to the local directory where the folders need to be created.  Using some PowerShell code that I think I found I am trying to create the folders from the text file that I have been modifying.
I need the leading zeros preserved in the folder name so I can reference back to the database later in the project.  My problem is that when I run the PowerShell script, no folders are created.  I think I have the problem isolated to the pattern definition, but don't understand what is wrong.

Input txt file example

```
001132884
001454596
001454602
001454605
001454606
001454601
001107119
001454600
001454608
```

PowerShell script

```
$folder="Customerdocuments";   # Directory to place the new folders in.
$txtFile="E:\dirtext.txt";     # File with list of new folder-names
$pattern="\d+.+";              # Pattern that lines must match      


Get-Content $txtFile | %{

    if($_ -match $pattern)
    {
        mkdir "$folder\$_";
    }
}
```

Comment: `%` (foreach object) will be interpreting the content as **one** line. You can see this if you replace your foreach with `| % { write-host $_ hello }` you can see that there is only one "hello" and it is at the end of all the numbers. This means that `$_` will never match the string "001132884" becuase it is actualy the whole document.

Comment: Your code should work fine if you put each number on its own line in the TXT file

Comment: your code `$pattern="\d+.+"` says that the text lines must match `one or more digits plus one or more of any character type`. that otta work, but a more accurate pattern would be `\d{9}` - nine digits. ///// however, why bother? your text file should NEVER have anything other than 9 digit numeric strings ... so the pattern test seems unneeded.

Answer (score 1):

- I'm missing a clear question/error report.
- Your pattern takes all digits <s>(greedy)</s> from input `\d+`
  ***and*** requires at least one other (any) character `.+` which isn't present in your sample file.
- So your issue isn't related to leading zeroes.
- Better specify exactly 9 digits and put that into a Where-object,
- The path from $folder will be relative to the current folder and should be build using `Join-Path`
- As mkdir is just a wrapper function for [New-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-5.1) and it supports piped input I'd use it directly.

```
$folder="Customerdocuments";   # Directory to place the new folders in.
$txtFile="E:\dirtext.txt";     # File with list of new folder-names
$pattern="^\d{9}$"             # Pattern that lines must match      

Get-Content $txtFile | Where-Object {$_ -match $pattern}|
    New-Item -Path {Join-Path $folder $_} -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
}
```

Comment: I have to correct myself the pattern `\d+.+` is not greedy

Comment: You do need to correct yourself, but not the "greedy" part :) `\d+` is indeed greedy, and `\d+.+` will cause the engine to match all digits against `\d+` before backtracking at least once in order to satisfy `.+`. You can easily prove this by moving `\d+` into an atomic group: `1234 -match '(?>\d+).+'` (returns `$false`) :)

Comment: Thank you, I was totally off the train track.